# Trying to scrape data from books.toscrape.com using for-loops and getting data from only 1 page instead of all 50

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am brand new to web-scraping with Python and have been trying to collect data from books.toscrape.com and export it to a CSV file. I want to collect all of the data from all 50 pages using a for-loop. This is what I have so far

```
#What I need to extract from the page in order to perform my analysis:
# -Pages
# -Prices
# -Ratings
# -Title
# -URLs(images)

import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import requests


#Creating empty lists to append the extracted data to later.
pagesList=[]
pricesList=[]
ratingsList=[]
titleList=[]
urlsList=[]

#Dictionary containing all of the data scraped from the site.
book_data={'Title':titleList,'Price':pricesList,'Ratings':ratingsList,'URL':urlsList}

#Number of pages to be selected
no_of_pages = 50

#Looping through the required pages and selecting the pages accordingly.
for i in range(1,no_of_pages+1): #to include the last page
    #This url variable will follow the generic URL replacing the page number according to the output of the for loop.
    url=('https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{}.html'.format(i))
    pagesList.append(url) #adding all of the content of the respective pages to the pages list

print("Number of pages: ",len(pagesList))
print(pagesList)

#Using requests to get the items from the page and convert it from request object to beautiful soup object, then checking it.
for item in pagesList:
    page=requests.get(item)
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser') 
    
#Structures the output when printing the soup variable
print(soup.prettify())

#Get all of the titles for the title list and append them to the title list without the tags
for t in soup.findAll('h3'):
    titles=t.getText()
    titleList.append(titles)

#print(titleList)

#Find all of the prices (they are in the <p> tag) and display them to check that it worked.
for p in soup.find_all('p', class_='price_color'): #the 'p' tag is
    price=p.getText()
    pricesList.append(price)
    
#print(pricesList)

#Finding the ratings and adding them to the ratingsList out of the "star-rating" class
for s in soup.find_all('p', class_='star-rating'):
    for k,v in s.attrs.items(): #k = class and v = star-rating
        star=v[1] #using indexing to get the string value of the star-rating value
        ratingsList.append(star) #appending to the list
        print(star) #the star list now contains all of the star-ratings of the books

#print(ratingsList)

#Finding all of the image URLs in the image_container class
divs=soup.find_all('div', class_='image_container') #fetching all of the divs in this image_container class
#print(divs)
for thumbs in divs:
    tags=thumbs.find('img', class_='thumbnail')
    #print(tags)
    links='https://books.toscrape.com/' + str(tags['src'])
    newlinks=links.replace('..','') #to get rid of the dots that appear and replace them with nothing
    urlsList.append(newlinks) #the URL list now contains all of the URLs of the book images

#print(urlsList)

#Dictionary containing all of the data scraped from the site.
web_data={'Title':titleList,'Price':pricesList,'Ratings':ratingsList,'URL':urlsList}

#Making sure all of the arrays are of the same length, unless Pandas indexing will not work
print(len(titleList))
print(len(pricesList))
print(len(ratingsList))
print(len(urlsList))

#Converting dictionary to a Pandas dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(web_data)
#Checking the dataframe conversion worked
df

#Changing the index to start from 1 instead of 0
df.index+=1

#Getting rid of the currency symbol in the Price column
#[x.strip('Â£') for x in df.Price]
df['Price']=df['Price'].str.replace('Â£','')

#Sort by the highest price
df.sort_values(by='Price',ascending=False, inplace = True) #so the changes reflect in the original sort

#Converting the Ratings column from string to the corresponding integer
df['Ratings']=df['Ratings'].replace({'Three':3,'One':1,'Two':2,'Four':4,'Five':5})
df

#Checking the data types to make sure price and ratings converted to correct dtypes
df.dtypes

#Converting the price column from object to float
df['Price']=df['Price'].astype(float)
df.dtypes

df.to_csv('bookstore.csv')
```

It looks like the exported CSV only contains 20 rows of data and I'm not sure where that data is coming from (the exact page). I've spent more time than I'd care to admit on this and I was too embarrassed to ask because it's probably something super simple I'm missing. If anyone could help me on this I would greatly appreciate it.

I suspect the issue is with this code:

```
#Number of pages to be selected
no_of_pages = 50

#Looping through the required pages and selecting the pages accordingly.
for i in range(1,no_of_pages+1): #to include the last page
    #This url variable will follow the generic URL replacing the page number according to the output of the for loop.
    url=('https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{}.html'.format(i))
    pagesList.append(url) #adding all of the content of the respective pages to the pages list
```

I just am not sure what the issue is.

I'm only getting 20 rows of data when I should be getting around 1,000.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating the `pagesList` but operate only on the last `soup`, because your identation of the loops that follow is not correct.

```
...
for item in pagesList:
    page=requests.get(item)
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')

for ...
```

So you could correct that behavior to get closer to your result:

```
...
for item in pagesList:
    page=requests.get(item)
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')

    for ...
```

or use the following example, that avoids the several loops and lists.

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

book_data=[]

no_of_pages = 50

for i in range(1,no_of_pages+1):
    url=('https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{}.html'.format(i))
    page=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
    for e in soup.select('article'):
        book_data.append({
            'title':e.h3.get_text(strip=True),
            'price':e.select_one('.price_color').text[2:],
            'additional':'data'
        })

pd.DataFrame(book_data)
```

Comment: I used your solution above, and I now have 1,000 rows of data. Thank you so much. I can't believe I overlooked the necessity of the nested for-loop. My headache is now over. This shows how much I still have to learn.

Comment: Any idea how I can get the ratings in there and converted from a string to an int? I tried applying the same logic and couldn't get it.

Comment: You could use `'ratings':e.p.get('class')[-1]` to get the class of the rating - your replacement in the pandsa series with the `dict` should work.